# pandas.Series: cannot create from custom dict-derived class

Tags: python, pandas

I have a class `ObjDict` which inherits from `dict` and provides `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` helpers:

```
class ObjDict(dict):    
    def __init__(self, dic):
        super().__init__(dic)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def __delattr__(self, key):
        del self[key]

    def __getstate__(self):
        return dict(self)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        super().update(state)
```

It allows to access keys as if they were attributes:

```
data = ObjDict({
    'a': 1.,
    'b': 2.,
    'c': 3.
})
assert data.a == 1
```

I recently updraded my `pandas` version (`0.19.2` -> `1.2.1`), and where previously the following worked:

```
print(pandas.__version__)

s = pandas.Series(data)
print(type(s))
print(s)
```

> ```
> 0.19.2
> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
> a    1.0
> b    2.0
> c    3.0
> dtype: float64
> ```

I now get an exception thrown:

```
print(pandas.__version__)

s = pandas.Series(data)
print(type(s))
print(s)
```

> ```
> 1.2.1
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-103-7e6489c85700> in <module>
>      27 print(pandas.__version__)
>      28 
> ---> 29 s = pandas.Series(data)
>      30 print(type(s))
>      31 print(s)
>
> ~/src/foo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in
> __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
>     235         else:
>     236 
> --> 237             name = ibase.maybe_extract_name(name, data, type(self))
>     238 
>     239             if is_empty_data(data) and dtype is None:
>
> ~/src/foo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py
> in maybe_extract_name(name, obj, cls)
>    5955     If no name is passed, then extract it from data, validating hashability.
>    5956     """
> -> 5957     if name is None and isinstance(obj, (Index, ABCSeries)):
>    5958         # Note we don't just check for "name" attribute since that would
>    5959         #  pick up e.g. dtype.name"""
>
> ~/src/foo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/generic.py
> in _check(cls, inst)
>      30     @classmethod  # type: ignore[misc]
>      31     def _check(cls, inst) -> bool:
> ---> 32         return getattr(inst, attr, "_typ") in comp
>      33 
>      34     dct = {"__instancecheck__": _check, "__subclasscheck__": _check}
>
> <ipython-input-103-7e6489c85700> in __getattr__(self, key)
>       4 
>       5     def __getattr__(self, key):
> ----> 6         return self[key]
>       7 
>       8     def __setattr__(self, key, value):
>
> KeyError: '_typ'
> ```

Note that if I use just a vanilla `dict`, it does work:

```
data = {
    'a': 1.,
    'b': 2.,
    'c': 3.
}

print(pandas.__version__)

s = pandas.Series(data)
print(type(s))
print(s)
```

> ```
> 1.2.1
> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
> a    1.0
> b    2.0
> c    3.0
> dtype: float64
> ```

Note also, that if I cast my `ObjDict` to a `dict`, it too works:

```
data = ObjDict({
    'a': 1.,
    'b': 2.,
    'c': 3.
})

print(pandas.__version__)

s = pandas.Series(dict(data))
print(type(s))
print(s)
```

> ```
> 1.2.1
> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
> a    1.0
> b    2.0
> c    3.0
> dtype: float64
> ```

**Questions:**

- What has changed in `pandas.Series` which is causing this exception?
- What do I need to add to my `ObjDict` class to enable passing it directly to the `Series` constructor?

Comment: Does a *vanilla* dictionary work in the new version of pandas?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Yes it does - sorry - I should have already stated that - I'll update the question

Comment: Looking at the traceback, I'd guess it's because `__getattr__` throws `KeyError`, not `AttributeError`, when an attribute isn't found, which breaks `getattr`'s handling of missing attributes. Can you try adding `if key not in self: raise AttributeError(key)`? See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__ - *"should either return the (computed) attribute value or raise an `AttributeError` exception"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's it! Thank you! If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll gladly accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we focus on the piece that's failing:

```
~/src/foo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/generic.py
in _check(cls, inst)
     30     @classmethod  # type: ignore[misc]
     31     def _check(cls, inst) -> bool:
---> 32         return getattr(inst, attr, "_typ") in comp
     33 
     34     dct = {"__instancecheck__": _check, "__subclasscheck__": _check}

<ipython-input-103-7e6489c85700> in __getattr__(self, key)
      4 
      5     def __getattr__(self, key):
----> 6         return self[key]
      7 
      8     def __setattr__(self, key, value):

KeyError: '_typ'
```

we can see that the problem is `getattr(inst, attr, "_typ")` calling `ObjDict#__getattr__` implementation and receiving a `KeyError`. Using the three-argument form of [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), you'd expect that to *never* throw an error (either you get the value of the attribute, or the default value `"_typ"`), so you wouldn't add any further handling around it.

However, the way `getattr` detects a missing attribute is by trying to access it and handling an `AttributeError`. This is part of the contract for attribute access; as the [data model documentation for `__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) explains:

> [`__getattr__`] should either return the (computed) attribute value or
> raise an `AttributeError` exception

In your case a missing attribute raises a `KeyError` exception instead, `ObjDict#__getattr__` -> `self[key]` -> `dict#__getitem__`. This isn't handled by `getattr`, whose caller wasn't prepared for any exception at all.

To fix this, you need to reimplement `__getattr__` to follow the description above, e.g. with:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    try:
        return self[key]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError(key)
```

or:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    if key not in self:
        raise AttributeError(key)
    return self[key]
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your questions, nothing actually changed in `pandas.Series`. But the `__getattr__` is throwing a `KeyError` when an attribute is not found in the class tree.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) states it as follows, note the last sentence:

> **`object.__getattr__(self, name)`**
>
> Called when the default attribute access fails with an `AttributeError`
> (either `__getattribute__()` raises an `AttributeError` because name is
> not an instance attribute or an attribute in the class tree for `self`;
> or `__get__()` of a name property raises `AttributeError`). This method
> should either return the (computed) attribute value or raise an
> `AttributeError` exception.

The following script works:

```
import pandas


class ObjDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, dic):
        super().__init__(dic)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key not in self: 
            raise AttributeError(key)
        return self[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def __delattr__(self, key):
        del self[key]

    def __getstate__(self):
        return dict(self)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        super().update(state)


data = ObjDict({
    'a': 1.,
    'b': 2.,
    'c': 3.
})
assert data.a == 1

print(pandas.__version__)

s = pandas.Series(data)
print(type(s))
print(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! If jonrsharpe doesn't add an answer in due course I'll accept yours

Comment: Ah he beat me, sure thing, happy to help!